# When route url is same as the package name, it does not work

Tags: laravel, routes, package, composer-php

I have a lot of URLs in my package routes, but one of them does not seem to work.

When the route is as follows:

```
Route::get('package_name', 'DashboardController@dashboard');
```

It does not work, but when it's something as below:

```
Route::get('something', 'DashboardController@dashboard');
```

Then it works with no problem.

Comment: With that information, it's difficult to diagnose. You must have some other code influencing the routes. Do you have a wildcard or catch-all style route defined also? Is there already a route with that URI defined, or do you define the same route URI again later? Also, what does "not work" mean? Do you get an error?

Comment: on your machine try php artisan route:list - you'll get a list with all registered routes. Maybe this helps you debugging

Comment: @jtwes Yeah I tried that, the route is there, and the URL is correct, but it does not work when I try to access it

Comment: @AkenRoberts I have a route as `Route::get('package_name/{something}', 'DashboardController@dashboard');` but my primary route has no wild card, it's just the way I specified above, and it's there when I run `php artisan route:list`

Comment: you can use `php artisan route:list` in your command terminal to know if the route you input is registered. maybe your problem is you used `get::resource` I think

Comment: What do you mean by *it does not work* ? Please improve the question and describe in detail what you expect and what's the actual behavior with those two lines of code.

Comment: @codeformoney Nope, I did not use `get::resource` neither `Route::resource`

Comment: @NicolaiFröhlich when I try to access the route by `localhost:8000/package_name` it throws **The requested resource `/package_name` was not found on this server.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why I had this problem because I was publishing a folder into the public directory with the same name as the package name.